# Cannot properly compile play services for libgdx

Tags: android-studio, gradle, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

So I've been trying to add google play services for my game.
First thing I did was add the dependency to the gradle file. This is how it looks now:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "My First Game"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.3'
        roboVMVersion = '2.1.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
        googlePlayVersion = '9.4.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-android:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$googlePlayVersion"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

[Here is a picture of the packages I have installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxgg7.png)

However I still can't use the library and if I try to make for example an AdView (which I should now be able to) it goes red and can't be identified, however I can Alt+Enter to

```
Add library 'play-services-ads-lite-9.4.0' to classpath
```

If I add that, it adds the following line to the **module** (not project) gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:9.4.0'
```

[and I get this gradle error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c556n.png)

If I go to:

```
/home/user/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android
```

I can see the folders play-services, play-services-ads, etc, so I know they are there!

Thank you for taking the time to look into my problem. All help is appreciated!

**EDIT: It has come to my attention that you might need the code:** `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.

I'm not sure where this should be however it says i need a file google-services.json. Not sure you should need this? Here is where i place the above line of code:

```
project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-android:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$googlePlayVersion"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

**EDIT2:** if I try to put the dependency as well as the "apply plugin" in this file instead of the project gradle I get the same result in the fork of an error message saying that google-services.json is missing. This is my module android gradle:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 23
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.oscarboking.myfirstgame"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}
// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if (outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}
task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.oscarboking.myfirstgame/AndroidLauncher'
}
// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [project.configurations.compile]
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}
// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If I try to use anything in the library I can alt+enter to the dependency however it tries to add it to the **core module** gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0'` in my project gradle and `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0'` in my android module gradle.

I'm also using google analytics, so the first one or two imports may be unnecessary.

Maybe you have to clean the project/remove the .gradle folder.

Comment: where in your gradle file do you use `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`? I didn't have any dependency in the android module however adding this does not resolve the problem.

Comment: I use it in my android module gradle file, right after the dependencies{}